# Prevent Object relationship from being created if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have the following database model and marshmallow schema. The object is saved as a whole. When we are updating the object it is done through a form and the whole object is changed at once. The issue that is occurring is if I want to change the Status and that ID doesn't exist in the database it is just creating it and adding it to the table rather than throwing an error that the primary key doesn't exist. How do I avoid this?

```
class BulkLane(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "bulk_lane_form"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    statusCd = db.Column("status_cd", db.String(1), db.ForeignKey("status_cd.status_cd"))
    status = db.relationship(Status)
    originId = db.Column("origin_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("supplier_whse.id"))
    origin = db.relationship(SupplierWarehouse)
    workingDaysId = db.Column("working_days_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("work_week.id"))
    workingDays = db.relationship(WorkWeek, foreign_keys=[workingDaysId])
    shippingDaysId = db.Column("shipping_days_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("work_week.id"))
    shippingDays = db.relationship(WorkWeek, foreign_keys=[shippingDaysId])
    transportationDaysId = db.Column("transportation_days_id",
                                 db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("work_week.id"))
    transportationDays = db.relationship(WorkWeek, foreign_keys=[transportationDaysId])



class BulkLaneSchema(marshmallow.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = BulkLane
        sqla_session = db.session

    id = fields.Integer()
    status = fields.Nested(StatusSchema())
    origin = fields.Nested(SupplierWarehouseSchema())
    workingDays = fields.Nested(WorkWeekSchema())
    shippingDays = fields.Nested(WorkWeekSchema())
    transportationDays = fields.Nested(WorkWeekSchema())


bulk_lane_schema = BulkLaneSchema()
bulk_lanes_schema = BulkLaneSchema(many=True)
```

Comment: query the db with all the attributes to check if id is present or not. Primary key(not composite) has autoincrement feature by default. So if it is a new object it will insert without questioning. In order to check if the id is present you need to query db

Comment: I guess I assumed that the ORM would automatically check to see if they exist when updating the whole object. It is just a pain to have to validate each nested attribute. Thanks!